# NavigationView menu does not update

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigation, android-navigationview

I am writing here about an issue that was introduced when we migrated from the AppCompat library to the AndroidX library. While doing so, we switched from `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` to  `com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView` and that’s when the following issue started.

In our NavigationView design, in order to save space, we implemented an expandable menu, so that when users clicks on the “more” button, the menu expands to show more options. It starts off with only some options visible, and the rest are not visible, as follows;

---

- Option 1
- Option 2
- More…

---

Upon clicking on the “More...” button, the menu expands to;

---

- Option 1
- Option 2
- Option 3
- Option 4
- Option 5
- Option 6

---

To do this we used following code;

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    ....
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_more)
    {
        item.setVisible(false); // hide the “More” item
        getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_option_3).setVisible(true);
        getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_option_4).setVisible(true);
        getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_option_5).setVisible(true);
        getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_option_6).setVisible(true);
        return true;
    }
    .......
    return false;
}
```

Well, this code has worked in the past, but when we migrated to using the androidx library, poof, it stopped working. Well, it did work a bit. The “More...” button got hidden, but the previously hidden options, were not being displayed.
As, it took me many hours to solve this issue, and to save others this headache, I will explain the issue and the solution.

The first thing to do in such cases, is to look at the source code. As the code is open source, I was able to get it at github. At first glance I didn’t get smarter. I found that the [NavigationView](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationView.java) has a [NavigationMenuPresenter](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java) object field (called `presenter`), that has a method called  [updateMenuView()](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java#L125) which calls [adapter.update()](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java#L545), which calls [prepareMenuItems()](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java#L554) and `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This sounded like the needed fix, so using reflection, we accessed and called the `updateMenuView()` method, but surprisingly, it did not help!

So, I decided to take it to the extreme, and see what happens if I call `getMenu().clear()`, and believe it or not, nothing happened. It seems that any changes made to Menu **after** the `NavigationView` is shown, are ignored. But a quick look through source code, I could not see any reason for that.

So how do I solve this issue? I tried using the latest alpha version of the library, but I still have the same issue.

Well, after much work, I found the solution. It's actually simple. Just hold on for the answer.

Lionscribe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I was back to the source code, searching for some clue, when I fell upon a method called [setUpdateSuspended(boolean updateSuspended)](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java#L712). Well, that sounded suspicious! I searched for usage of this method, and found it being called in the [onClick](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java#L408) callback. Here is a minimized version of the code;

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      NavigationMenuItemView itemView = (NavigationMenuItemView) view;
      setUpdateSuspended(true);
      MenuItemImpl item = itemView.getItemData();
      boolean result = menu.performItemAction(item, NavigationMenuPresenter.this, 0);
      setUpdateSuspended(false);
  }
```

Bingo! It seems that while handling clicks, the `NavigationView` suspends and will not recognize any changes done to menu. I am not sure the reason for this, but as we were updating the menu in the `onNavigationItemSelected` callback, which is called by the `onClick` method, the menu updates are ignored.

Well, once I understood the issue, the solution was simple and clean. I just wrapped the code in a `Runnable`, and posted it, so that it runs **after** the `onClick` method returns, and `setUpdateSuspended` is set back to false. Here is the updated code;

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    ....
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_more)
    {
        final MenuItem itemFinal = item;
        post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                    getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_option_3).setVisible(true);
                    getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_option_4).setVisible(true);
                    getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_option_5).setVisible(true);
                    getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_option_6).setVisible(true);
                    itemFinal.setVisible(false);  // hide the “More” item
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    .......
    return false;
}
```

Viola! The expandable menu now works like it used to, the hidden items are now being shown!

I hope this will be of help to others with same issue.

Lionscribe

Comment: Big tnx for sharing this info, it helped me a lot. Tnx ;]